# Why does orderBy in F# not result in an ORDER BY in SQL?

Tags: sql, linq, f#, sql-order-by

I'm currently working on a small project that uses USA county data. I have no problems ordering the data in a `Seq.orderBy`, but as there is a `sortBy` in the query expression I would expect the results to be sorted. This is not the case.

```
type SysData = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=ROME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SysData;Integrated Security=True">
type County = { State : string; SSA : string }

let counties =
    let db = SysData.GetDataContext()
    query {
        for c in db.CountyMatrix do
        sortBy c.Countyssa
        select { State = c.State; SSA = c.Countyssa }
        distinct
    }
```

Now, the above is what I'm executing, but my results end up looking like so:

```
...
{State = "OR";
 SSA = "38030";}
{State = "GA";
 SSA = "11630";}
{State = "WA";
 SSA = "50130";}
{State = "MN";
 SSA = "24740";}
{State = "KY";
 SSA = "18030";}
{State = "MO";
 SSA = "26970";}
{State = "DC";
 SSA = "09000";}
...
```

And the query sent to my local SQL Server instance is displayed in IntelliTrace as so:

```
USE [SysData];

GO

SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[state] AS [Item1], [t0].[countyssa] AS [Item2]
FROM [dbo].[CountyMatrix] AS [t0]
```

Note the lack of an `ORDER BY`, which I was expecting to be there because of the query expression's `sortBy c.Countyssa`.

Any ideas as to why I'm not getting sorted data out of `counties`? I'm aiming to make this as clean as possible to show as a small example to my employer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `order by` in your sql query so result will be unordered

Comment: @NoDisplayName Right, I understand that. I'll update my question to reflect this ambiguity. The thing is, though, I was expecting an ORDER BY in the SQL query, as it's generated by the query expression itself.

Comment: It may have something to do with the use of Distinct. Have you tried without it? Distinct doesn't have to retain order, and the sequence of elements in F# seems to make a difference.

Comment: @jessehouwing That does work. Is there a way to utilize `distinct` still or would `|> Seq.distinct` after the end of the expression be the better path?

Comment: Are you allowed to write it as: `for c in db.CountyMatrix do
        let c = { State = c.State; SSA = c.Countyssa }
        distinct
        sortBy c.SSA
        select c`? 

My F# is not up to par to know for sure...

Comment: @jessehouwing That most definitely worked, do you think you could throw that as an answer and explain what's happening? I'd love to throw internet points your way, ha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the keywords is important. If you read the description carefully, then SortBy will sort the elements that have been selected so far. Distinct will remove duplicates so far (but there is nothing in there about keeping order), etc. Each of these keywords acts on the one before it, but keep in mind that it may also undo something that was done before (like the sorting).

See the [description of each of these keywords here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx).

```
for c in db.CountyMatrix do 
    let c = { State = c.State; SSA = c.Countyssa } 
    distinct 
    sortBy c.SSA 
    select c
```

You may need to use a temporary variable to catch the data type in order to distinct and sort them.

Comment: That's not an anonymous type, it's an instance of the County record. F# does not support anonymous types.

Comment: That would be my mistake from translating C# to F# :). Told you, my F# is rusty at best.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this today.  Here's an alternate solution using a subquery:

```
let counties =
    let db = SysData.GetDataContext()
    query {
        for result in (query {
            for c in db.CountyMatrix do
            select { State = c.State; SSA = c.Countyssa }
            distinct
        }) do
        sortBy (result.SSA)
        select result
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the `sortBy` expression after `select`.

```
let counties =
    let db = SysData.GetDataContext()
    query {
        for c in db.CountyMatrix do
        select { State = c.State; SSA = c.Countyssa }
        sortBy c.Countyssa
        distinct
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this results in a compile-time error. I think it's just a ordering issue in terms of the statements on this answer.